# How do I get the type of constructor parameter via reflection?

Tags: php, reflection

I'm using type hinting on my constructor parameter list like so:

```
public function __construct(FooRepository $repository)
```

Is there a way to use the PHP Reflection API to get the hinted type? In other words, I want a reflection function that I can call to somehow get back the string "FooRepository". I've tried getting the constructor via reflection and then getting the parameters if the constructor, but I don't see anything that will give me the string of the hinted type.

Comment: Eventually, this was written into Laravel's IoC Container - bravo @taylorotwell!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try this out.

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct(Bar $test) {
    }
}

class Bar {
    public function __construct() {
    }
}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$params = $reflection->getConstructor()->getParameters();
foreach ($params AS $param) {
    echo $param->getClass()->name . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: +1 That's awesome. And I was doing it the a lengthy way before. They really should document Reflection one day.

Comment: This only works for classes, any other hint will fail with a "Class *** does not exist" exception.

Comment: @AlixAxel Actually only classes and arrays are allowed for type hinting. You should check `ReflectionParameter::isArray()` first

Comment: @hek2mgl even better `$param->getType()->getName()` for getting the type. That doesn't require retrieving a class and allows scalar types as well.

Comment: simshaun: what is alternate to `$param->getClass()->name` as `getClass()` has been deprecated in php 8.

Comment: @C.F.G - The PHP docs say to use `getType()`

Comment: @simshaun: I couldn't find that docs. you mean `$param->getType()->name`?!!

Answer (score 0):

**Check out PHP 5.4**

They are planning to get out PHP 5.4 this year, which will have the reflection method (current in the dev builds) of **parameter->getHint()**

However, until 5.4 goes GA, I am using [ReflectionClass::getDocComment()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getdoccomment.php)

For example, you can specify it in @param.

```
// Adapted from meager's example
class Bar {}

class Foo {
    /**
    * @param MyType $value
    * @param array $value2
    */
    function __construct(Bar $value, array $value2) {
    }
}

// Regex
function getHint( $docComment, $varName ) {
    $matches = array();
    $count = preg_match_all('/@param[\t\s]*(?P<type>[^\t\s]*)[\t\s]*\$(?P<name>[^\t\s]*)/sim', $docComment, $matches);
    if( $count>0 ) {
        foreach( $matches['name'] as $n=>$name ) {
            if( $name == $varName ) {
                return $matches['type'][$n];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

$reflection = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$constructor= $reflection->getConstructor();
$docComment = $constructor->getDocComment();
$params = $constructor->getParameters();
foreach ($params AS $param) {
    $name = $param->getName();
    echo $name ." is ";
    //echo $param->getHint()."\n"; // in PHP 5.4
    echo getHint($docComment, $name)."\n"; // work around
}
```

Output:

```
value is MyType
value2 is array
```

Comment: +1, but PHP 5.4.7 and still no sign of `ReflectionParameter::getHint()` **:(**.

Comment: @AlixAxel, sadly I've moved away from PHP over the last several years due to complete lack of vision/focus from the language devs. :(

Comment: Oh, ok. Just out of curiosity, what did you chose to take it's place?

Comment: @AlixAxel Java mostly. Fancy it more than C#. Language has a great timeline. No ideal if PHP 6 will ever happen.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to get the hinted type, or the actual type? I can't see why you could want to get the hinted type, as you *know* it is 'FooRepository' or PHP would have raised an error.

You can get the actual type via [`get_class`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) and you can also find out if a object inherits from a given class with [`ReflectionClass::isSubclassOf`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.issubclassof.php).

Comment: I can see where this would come in handy in an MVC framework for dynamically loading the files for model classes and dynamically mapping post/get data to the objects.

Comment: @Twisted There is a difference between the **type** and the **hinted type**. Re-read my answer, you missed the point completely.

Comment: @meager Allow me to rephrase. I assert that there are many cases where you would want to know the hinted type. For example, you could easily create some setPropX(myType $value) methods in a ORM object class. Then, your ORM implementation can reflect to get the hint so that you know what type to cast to.