# how to get variable names of a parent function/method?

Tags: php, php-5.3

`debug_backtrace()` is only returning args array with names populated only with numbers, so maybe there are other hacks to get to parent scope context ?

Comment: there is even a request for that here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45736

Comment: Maybe you should also ask yourself, why you need such a mechanism. Often, this creates problems at some point or another. Why not create a new question where you explain what you're trying to achieve, how you currently handle it, and what better alternatives are, that do not make your code depend on the parent context?

Comment: I'm trying to write 'sanitize' method that would be run on other methods and check if given parameters are ok, for example are matching some regexes etc. - as you see from the post below, such mechanism exsits.

Comment: I'm aware that these mechanisms exist, but that's not the point. The question is still: What are you trying to achieve? Your description is very vague and only describes what it does to some extent, but the whys and how you intend to use that information remain unknown.

Comment: Well, again, I have a class with many methods, those methods need data to work, this data must accord to certain rules, so be bool or non empty string or match some regex. I easily could write ifs and elses in every of these methods, but that would be repeating task, so instead I written a function that needs to be run in a first line after method starts and it raises an error if input data doesn't match my rules. Then in the method I am sure that I'm operating on safe data. In the parameters of sanitize function I'm putting variable names I want to work with, so this function must reach utsid

Comment: "again" - no, your description has changed a lot. You no longer run the sanitize method `on` your methods, but rather call it from `within` your methods, which is quite a different thing. I know what you mean, I've done the same, although, I've just used numerical indexing to refer to the parameters, so I had one hack less. Anyway, I got thinking at some point: I realized I was working around the language rather than leverage it, and started wondering whether I hadn't been using the wrong language in the first place.

Comment: I read that they are planning to extend this reflection functionality in 5.4 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262350/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-constructor-parameter-via-reflection - there must be a big pressure on developers to do such things since many of these features are implemented but not documented yet.

Comment: @user393087 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1103/discussion-between-phant0m-and-user393087)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Reflector Function

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php

Example

```
function test($test){
    return $test;
}


$method = new ReflectionFunction('test');
var_dump( $method->getParameters() ); 

foreach($params as $param){
    echo $param->name.'<br/>';
}
```

Class Example using ReflectionMethod

```
class MyClass{

function test($test,$world){
    return $test;
}
}

$method = new ReflectionMethod('MyClass','test');
$params = $method->getParameters();

foreach($params as $param){
    echo $param->name.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Anyone help me how to use it in context of my question? There is very little documentation.

Comment: Could you provide some example how to use it in a class context ? Your example works, but if I do it in a class I get `Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Invalid method name __construct'`

Comment: For this you need the reflection method class, checkout my edit.