# PHP DI/IoC Container configuration for every object in Application or?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I have one question: Do I need to configure my DI/IoC Container for every object in application or just configure factories ?

Now I have something like this:

```
'serviceFactory' => function() use ($container) {
    return new \Application\Core\Factory\ServiceFactory($container->get('entityFactory'), $container->get('repositoryFactory'), $container->get('cache'), $container->get('file'), $container->get('image'));
},

'repositoryFactory' => function() use ($container) {
    return new \Application\Core\Factory\RepositoryFactory($container->get('database'), $container->get('queryBuilder'), $container->get('mapper'), $container->get('language'));
},

'entityFactory' => function() use ($container) {
    return new \Application\Core\Factory\EntityFactory($container->get('language'));
},
```

But then, application loads unnecessary objects into other objects that are not needed.

Example: In **BlogService** I do not use **File** class or **Image** class. In **ThumbnailService** I do, but I don't use **Entity** or **Repository** inside it.

So, do I need to import some lazy loading inside my DI/IoC Container or I need to write every Entity/Repository/Service/Controller connection like this:

```
'blogController' => function() use ($container) {
    return new \Application\Controller\BlogController($container->get('blogService'));
},

'blogService' => function() use ($container) {
    return new \Application\Service\BlogService($container->get('blog'), $container->get('categoryEntity'), $container->get('blogRepository'), $container->get('cache'));
},

'blogRepository' => function() use ($container) {
    return new \Application\Model\Repository\BlogRepository($container->get('database'), $container->get('queryBuilder'), $container->get('mapper'), $container->get('language'));
},

'blog' => function() use ($container) {
    return new \Application\Model\Entity\Blog($container->get('language'));
},

'thumbnailService' => function() use ($container) {
    return new \Application\Service\ThumbnailService($container->get('image'), $container->get('file'));
},
```

But this way I could be writing all 50-100 entities, repositories, services and controllers, maybe over-optimization ?

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

No, usually you need to register only types that can vary i.e concrete implementations of an abstraction. If you aren't using abstractions then a DI Container isn't that useful.

The DI Container should allow to register types using conventions e.g register all classes with the name needing in "Service" as services. This way you just define some 'rules' and the registration is done automatically regardless how many services you have in the app. At least this is how things are in .net , but clearly writing manually registration of 50-100 classes is a code smell.

**update**

It should look like this

```
 interface ISomeService {}

 class MyService implements ISomeService { }

 class OtherService
 {
     private $svc;
     function __construct(ISomeService $svc)
     {
         $this->svc=$svc;
     }

      function doStuff()
      {
          //do stuff using  $this->svc
      }
 }

 //DiContainer
 //here you you should register things (I don't know a container for php, I'll write what I'm using in C#, but you'll get the idea)
             container.RegisterTypes(myAssembly)
            .Where(type=>type.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .AsSelf()
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

The  code above tells the container to scan for all classes with the name ending in "Service" (my convention) and to automatically register them to be used when either that specific type is requested or an implementation of the interfaces implemented by that type.

In our example, it means when an instance of *OtherService* is requested from the container, the container knows to use the *MyService* type as the concrete type for *ISomeService* . The container looks into your constructor to detect what dependencies the object needs.

In order to properly use a DI Container, your (mvc) framework should be aware of it, because it isn't meant to be used directly by your app. There are cases where the Service Locator pattern is valid, but usually **the framework should use the container to create instances** of the services you need.

You configure the container when the app bootstraps (as part or integrated with your mvc framework) and that's it. Next, you just define interfaces and classes (services,repositories,event handlers etc). The only thing you should do is to come up with some conventions to allow your container to auto register classes based on them (such as naming your services "Service").

DI Containers first appeared in statically typed languages (java, C#) where it makes more sense to be used, compared to a dynamic language where you aren't constrained by a type (that's why I'm using type hinting in php). They're still useful but there're a bit harder to understand.

Comment: Hmmm you mean if I need to inject ThumbnailService it automatically detects and includes File and Image class, if not (else) then includes Repository, Entity... Now, im using container like this: `$container->get('ThumbnailService');`, but maybe i could use something like `$container->get('Service', 'Thumbnail');` and then it detects what to include and what not...

Comment: Thanks for example and hint ("The container looks into your constructor to detect what dependencies the object needs.") Found something interesting and I think this could be solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262350/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-constructor-parameter-via-reflection

Comment: One more question, you said that framework should be aware of DI Container, but how ? I have Router and Dispatcher. Router checks for current active url, parse it, and finds out which Controller and Action (method) with params should be included. Then I start Dispatcher to dispatch that controller. Should I inject DI Container into Dispatcher so it could dynamically load Controller => Service => Repository or ?

Comment: IMO you should use a framework which knows about DI Container, like Laravel, not building/modifying your own

Comment: I'm creating my own framework for learning purpose. Will look into Laravel to see how they worked this out.