# (PHP Reflection?) Create a new instance of a type hint given as parameter

Tags: php, reflection

Take a moment and look at these two simple classes:

```
use ValueObjects\Address;

class Person {

    private $address;

    public function setAddress(Address $address){
        $this->address = $address;
    }
}

class Address {
    private $line1 = "";
    private $line2 = "";
    private $city = "";
    private $state = "";
    private $zip = "";

    public function __construct($line1, $line2, $city, $state, $zip){
        $this->line1 = $line1;
        $this->line2 = $line2;
        $this->city = $city;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->zip = $zip;
    }

    public function getLine1(){ ... }
    public function getLine2(){ ... }
    // ...
}
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
// I have the class instance
$person = new Person();  

// I have the setter method name "setAddress"
$setter = "set".ucfirst("address");

// I have these parameters
$line1 = "123 Main St.";  
$line2 = "";
$city = "New York";
$state = "NY";
$zip = "10000";

// I only have the information you see above, how do I use that to set
// these values into $person? 
?????
```

I suppose I need to use some form of Reflection? (Also, I hear Reflection can have slow performance, so feel free to recommend any better performing approach if you know of one.)

Answer (score 0):

I would  just change the constructor to accept an key-value array.  Something like:

```
public function __construct($array){
 foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
    $this->$key = $value;
  }
}
```

Then, don't set variables, set keys in the array.   Such as

```
$data = array( 
'line1' => "123 Main St.",
'line2' => "",
'city' => "New York",
'state' => "NY",
'zip' => "10000",
);
```

Rather than use a lot of reflection, I tend to just implement loosely typed functions.   For example:

```
<?php

class Person {

    private $address;

    public function setAddress(Address $address){
        $this->address = $address;
    }

    // loosely typed setter
    public function _setAddress($data){
        $this->address = new Address($data);
    }
}

class Address {

    private $line1 = "";
    private $line2 = "";
    private $city = "";
    private $state = "";
    private $zip = "";

    public function __construct($array){
     foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
        $this->$key = $value;
      }
    }
}

$p = new Person();

$setter = "_setAddress";
$data = array(
    'line1' => "123 Main St.",
    'line2' => "",
    'city' => "New York",
    'state' => "NY",
    'zip' => "10000",
);

$p->$setter($data);

print_r($p);
```

Otherwise, if you use reflection (might be slower) it would be:

[How do I get the type of constructor parameter via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262350/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-constructor-parameter-via-reflection)

Comment: I considered that, but I weighed in favor of keeping the address value object immutable. However, this still doesn't solve the problem of getting an instance of Address when all I have is $person and the method name.

Comment: I need to use some sort of reflection on the setter method to get the type of its parameter so I can then instance a new one.

Comment: Since the types are known prior to compiling, I might use loosely typed setters (see above).

Answer (score 0):

I determined that the best solution is to avoid Reflection and instead build some sort of auto-mapper. You can see Jimmy Bogard has done [something like this in .net](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/01/23/automapper-the-object-object-mapper/). PHP doesn't have specified return types, but I think I work around that in some way.