# IoC container concept in PHP

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm trying to grasp the concept of IoC and Dependency Injection in PHP, So iv'e decided to go on and create a small framework and implement these design patterns.

i've created my own IoC class which you can find here 
https://gist.github.com/payamb/d8134ae0c5d09cda79ff

And i feed my configs like this to the IoC container at run time

```
 // --- Main Application
    [
        'name'      =>  'Application',
        'service'   =>  [
            'type'      =>  'constructor',
            'class'     =>  'Pebbles\Core\Application',
            'params'    =>  [
                'router'    =>  '*AltoRouter',
                'request'   =>  '*Request',
                'IoC'       =>  '*IoC'
            ],
            'call'      => [
                [
                    'method'    =>  'setRoutes',
                    'args'      =>  [$routes]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'lazy'      =>  FALSE
    ]
```

And the IoC class handle the dependency injection and initiliaztion.

By doing this i got my head around what actually IoC does and why is it important.

Here is how my front controller looks like :

```
// read $params from config file and pass it to IoC
$container = new \Pebbles\Core\IoC($params);
$container->getService('Application')->setEnvironment('dev')->run();
```

And this is the my Application class :

```
namespace Pebbles\Core;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
class Application
{
    protected $request;
    protected $router;
    protected $container;
    protected $environment;
    public function __construct(\AltoRouter $router, Request $request, IoC $container)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->container = $container;
    }
    public function setEnvironment($env)
    {
        $this->environment = $env;
        return $this;
    }
    public function run()
    {
        $match = $this->router->match();
        if ($match) {
            list ($controller, $action) = explode(':', $match['target']);
            $object = & $this->container->getService($controller);
            try {
                call_user_func_array([$object, $action], $match['params']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

But now i'm struggeling how to move forward from this point.
Do i have to create a config file for all of controllers and services i'm going to use in this project and feed them to IoC (lazy) ?
I mean if i'm going to have a bookingController, i have to create a config file for that and feed it to container in order to be able to use and route request to it.

but what if i have like 20 controller and 10 services ? is it still the right approach ? i'm not sure about that bit that injected the IoC itself to Application class,
but how else can i route requests if i don't have access to IoC container.

Am i making mistake in implementing IoC desgin pattern ?

Here is the github link to what my actual code looks like
https://github.com/payamb/Pebbles

Comment: why do you need a config file for your controller?

Comment: @watcher so IoC can initialize it and then i can route request to it.  if my controller depends on $dbHandler to be injected, the only way to make it work is to feed the IoC with instruction on how to create controller and let it initialize it. Am i correct ? :) and my question is , is this the right approach ? because soon I'll end up with like 20-30 conf to feed to my IoC

Comment: sure. that makes sense.  have you tried instead [inspecting the controller's constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262350/how-do-i-get-the-type-of-constructor-parameter-via-reflection) using reflection and trying to dynamically create objects instead of statically change them in a config file? your problem is that if any of your depedencies change, you have to change them in two spots, the constructor _and_ the config file which kind of defeats the whole point

Comment: @watcher Great !! thanks for the link and advice, yeah that make more sense now.
What about the Application class ? do you think is it good idea to inject container itself to Application class ? actually i don't see any other way to do it.

Comment: sure I don't see why not, that really just depends on you and how you want your solution to be architected. if I remember correctly, Laravel is a framework that's heavily based around having an IoC container which it's application class extends making it an IoC container also.

Comment: I think the mistake you are making is implementing your own DI container. There are plenty of containers available that are open source, battle tested, thread safe, and follow best practices. The world really doesn't need yet another one, and neither should you.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I just did it to get my around the concept of IoC , I'm just following 'create your own framework , throw it away and use a real framework' :) the sole purpose of this just to learn and use some of the mentioned design patterns.

Comment: I would study the Symfony2 Dependency Injection component.  It work similarly to Spring and might give you some ideas.